# Как правильно создать структуру проекта?

Tags: java, intellij-idea, java-ee

Создал web-project, без изначального добавления модуля web application, затем вручную добавил новый модуль в проект.
Проблем не было, пока дело не дошло до запуска приложения.
На скрине внизу структура почему-то не правильная, нету необходимых папок(WEB-INF)
[image: введите сюда описание изображения]

Из-за этого, stack trace выбивает ошибку ClassNotFoundException
Можно как-нибудь аккуратно без создания нового проекта сделать структуру правильной?